# Different behaviors for nested folders between classic and lightning

Tags: soql

As we knew, in classic view folder and report are in a two-level structure. We can not create folder under folder in classic mode.

Using SOQL like (Select OwnerId,Id from Report / Select from Folder), we can get reports and folders, and display them in flat view.

Lightning has enabled nested folders as new feature. 
So it seems that the folder-report is no longer a flat structure.

Can we get this kind of relationship by SOQL?

Answer (score 0):

It's not yet documented in the [`Folder` field reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Folder.htm), but there is now a `ParentId` field on the `Folder` sObject, with child relationship name `SubFolders`:

[image: relationship view]

This means you can do

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM SubFolders) FROM Folder
```

or

```
SELECT Id, Name, ParentId FROM Folder
```

and get back details of the hierarchy. Unfortunately, Salesforce doesn't let you traverse the `Parent` relationship using dot notation, for reasons I don't know:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Parent.Name FROM Folder
```

yields

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:18
>   Didn't understand relationship 'Parent' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.